# How does an asp.net MVC request fits in pipeline?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As far as ASP.NET (.aspx) page request concern, I know that:

"Application Pool forward the request to worker process to load the ISAPI Extension which will create an HTTPRuntime Object to Process the request via HTTPModule and HTTPHanlder. After that the ASP.NET Page LifeCycle events starts."

[image]

Now my question is, where does the ASP.NET MVC request (extension-less) fit into the above pipeline (as per the picture shown)? Where is it different? How does "aspnet_isapi.dll" find an extension-less URL?

Please advise!